# USB HDD replace by "ubuntu" in boot order

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

After installing Ubuntu, it seems that USB HDD has been removed from the boot configuration entries.

In the GRUB Boot Menu, I only see:

```
ubuntu
Windows Boot Manager
SATA HDD: 
SATA CD: 
USB CD:
USB FDD:
NETWORK
```

**How do I remove the "ubuntu" entry and get back "USB HDD"?**

Comment: Issue is that I cannot boot from my USB HDD anymore since it does not appear in the list of Boot Device Priority. I have a samsung laptop, bios- Phoenix SecureCore Tiano. i didn't installed ubuntu on the usb hdd.

Comment: am trying to boot elementary os from my pendrive but there is no usb hdd,i installed grub customizer to remove the ubuntu entry from boot order even that don't work !! yes am booting directly to bios. if i have format the hard drive, do you think it will remove the entry ?